# Multiple JS with submit button

Tags: javascript, html, forms, salesforce, form-submit

I have created a form that is submitting the form in its entirety and preventing the page from reloading locally.

As soon as it is posted to the website and we try and plug in the handler (SalesForce). The form still submits but the page reloads and we cant have that. As there is data that reveals once the "submit" button is clicked. The button is controlling multiple JS and functions.

Can anyone look at the code and see where the problem lies?

```
<div>
<div class="columns medium-6">

<script type="text/javascript">
                function randomnumber() {
                    document.forms[0].Code.value=(Math.round(Math.random()*999999+1)); }
                onload=randomnumber
            </script>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" id="firstname" aria-describedby="firstname" placeholder="First Name">

                <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" id="lastname" aria-describedby="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">

                <label for="email">Email address</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" aria-describedby="email" placeholder="Email">

                <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone" aria-describedby="phone" placeholder="Phone">

                <!--<input type="hidden" name="Owner" value="00G1a000001I7EA"> -->
                <input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="CSF">
                <input type="hidden" name="visitor_type" value="NEW-CUST">
                <input type="hidden" name="party_size" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="source" value="Love Happens Here">
                <input type="hidden" name="webtoleadstoreid" value="a0C1a00000BJhea">
                <input type="hidden" name="company" value="New Guest">
                <input type="hidden" name="reason_visit" value="other">

            <button type="submit" id="randomNumber" onclick="javascript:toggle(); return false;" class="btn btn-primary" value="Generate Code">Submit</button>

                <script language="javascript"> 
                    function toggle() {
                        var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
                        var text = document.getElementById("randomNumber");
                        if(ele.style.display == "block") {
                            ele.style.display = "none";
                            text.innerHTML = "show";
                        }
                        else {
                            ele.style.display = "block";
                            text.innerHTML = "Submit";
                        }
                    }

                    function showdiv()  {
                        var error = false;
                            //validate your form.
                        if(error == true){ return true;}
                        else
                        {
                            //show div
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                </script>

                <div id="toggleText" style="display: none">
                <label for="code">Code</label>
                <input type="text" name="Code" readonly id="Code" aria-describedby="code" placeholder="code">
                <p> Check your email for the coupon code and details. Thanks again for your participation in our Share & Win contest, winners will be announced on <strong>February 14th.</strong></p>
                </div>

            </div>    
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you try using Ajax if you don't want the page to reload?

Comment: I will try anything at this point.

Comment: Ajax is being blocked on the backend and need to use JS only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said, you can use Ajax to achieve what you want. 
Here are a few links that will help you in that direction

[Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)

[Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)

If they don't really help you, try googling Ajax, you will definitely find a site that will explain everything to you.

Comment: Figured it out. Thank you for your help Alf Moh